# Nodejs express API one sequelize(db) instance to all models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, sequelize.js

I'm new to Nodejs and learning the api development from a udemy course `https://www.udemy.com/api-development/learn/v4/content` the course use mongodb(mongoose) but I'm now trying to replace `mongoose` with `Sequelize`

ill try to explain the problem in detail.
i have a file db.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import config from './config';
export default callback => {
    let db = mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl);
    callback(db);
}
```

i replaced it with sequelize

```
import Sequelize from 'Sequelize';
import config from './config';

export default callback => {
    let db = new Sequelize(config.dbname, config.dbuser, config.dbpassword, {
      host: config.dbhost,
      dialect: 'mariadb',

      pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        idle: 10000
      }
    });

    callback(db);

}
```

it takes this db instance and pass it to middleware and controllers in routes.js file

```
import express from 'express';
import config from '../config';
import middleware from '../middleware';
import initializeDb from '../db';
import restaurant from '../controller/restaurant';

let router = express();

//connect to db
initializeDb(db => {

    //internal middleware
    router.use(middleware({config,db}));

    // api routes
    router.use('/restaurant',restaurant({config,db}));
});

export default router;
```

and pass this routes to app.use when it creates the server

```
import http from 'http';
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import config from './config';
import routes from './routes'; //her it imports the routes and pass it to app.use below

let app = express();
app.server = http.createServer(app);

// middleware
// parse application/json

app.use(bodyParser.json({
    limit:config.bodyLimit
}));


// passport config


//api routes v1
app.use('/v1',routes); //here it pass the routes

var listener = app.server.listen(config.port,function(){
    console.log(`Started on port ${listener.address().port}`);
});


export default app;
```

so at this point the db instance is now available on my controllers here is how:
this is one of the controller

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import  { Router } from 'express';
import Restaurant from '../model/restaurant';

export default({config,db}) => {
    let api = Router();

    // '/v1/restaurant' - Read
    api.get('/',(req,res) => {
        // i have db available here
    }); 



    return api;
}
```

at this point i need the db instance in the model so i can just import it in the controller(return model to the controller) instead of using db instance in the controller `import Restaurant from '../model/restaurant';` where `Restaurant` will be sequelize model

but since i dont have db available in the model, one way is to initialize db in the model file but i m thinking if there is the way to get the already initialized db instance it would be better, in `mongoose` it generates model using schema but for sequelize i need to have the db instance in order to create the model, below is the mongoose model.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let restaurantSchema = new Schema({
    name:String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Restaurant',restaurantSchema);
```

any help would be appreciated, or if there is a better way of doing that please suggest

Answer (score 0):

See the best practice [here](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example) :

Have a look at models directory which should contains all your models plus the index.js file, which is used to instantiate a new sequelize instance and import all the models in a single object.

Now, wherever you need to talk to your DB, all you need to do will be something like:

```
var models  = require('../models');
models.User.create({ ... });
```